# Problem with build version when publishing APK to Play Store

Tags: android, azure-devops, google-play, devops

I've seen lots of answers but most of them are out of date. I'm trying to publish my android application to Play Store using Azure DevOps pipelines.

I'm facing an issue with the version code of the APK. Getting the following error:

> **APK specifies a version code that has already been used**

Anyone have an idea about how I can increment the version code and name that exist in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I think we should change it in the CI pipeline.

Here's my CD pipeline:

[image]

Comment: this problem can only be fixed by changing the versionCode  in the defaultConfig

Comment: What do you mean by changing it in the default config? Where is the defaultConfig?

Comment: build.gradle (Module:app)

Comment: Ohh you mean each time I want to publish to play store I'll fix it from my gradle. I know that but couldn't that be done some how in the build or release pipeline?

Comment: Are u trying to publish an update of your app? or have you added this app previously but then deleted it with the same package name and now trying again to add?

Comment: @PrajwalW I'm trying to publish an update of the app, yes the application is added previously on playstore but not deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For every update that you add for your exisiting app, u will have to
>   increment its value.

**To do so:**

1. Open your build.gradle (Module: app)
2. Increase the Version Code by 1 to your exisiting version code. ( This should be a positive integer number only).
3. Also, change your Version Name to show differentiation.

Comment: So you mean each time I want to publish to play store, I need to change the version name and code manually in my android project?

Comment: Yes thats a must as it is the way how the Google Playstore differentiates your every app release from its every updates of your app. So at the end, before building the apk, u hv to increase the versioning and build apk and then release.