# Error "APK specifies a version code that has already been used.." while deploying to Google Play store from Azure DevOps

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to deploy our Nativescript app to the Google Play Store using a YML pipeline in Azure DevOps. There is a deployment task that automatically increases the versionCode and versionNumber, which always used to work fine.

However now that we upload, I get this error:

> ##[error]Error: Failed to upload the bundle /Users/runner/work/1/_Android/app-release.aab. Failed with message:
> Error: APK specifies a version code that has already been used..

I see that the latest version in Google Play store is 1.0.3601

[image: VersionCode in Google Play store]

In the release pipeline I see that the versionCode generated is 1.0.3603 and versionName is 1.0.3604

[image: VersionCode in Azure DevOps release pipeline]

How can this be solved? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [User Kingston Fortune - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7192983/kingston-fortune), make sure to change `versionCode` and versionName in **build.gradle** file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.packageId"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2      <-- increment this by 1
    versionName "2.0"  <-- this is the version that shows up in playstore, 
                           remember that the versioning scheme goes as follows.
                           first digit = major breaking changes version
                           second digit = minor changes version
                           third digit = minor patches and bug fixes.
                           e.g versionName "2.0.1"
}
```

References: [Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772407/upload-failed-you-need-to-use-a-different-version-code-for-your-apk-because-you/52853585#52853585) , [Problem with build version when publishing APK to Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520193/problem-with-build-version-when-publishing-apk-to-play-store) , https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-google-play-deploy/issues/31 and https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning

Comment: The store actually doesn't care about the versionName-  you can call as many builds "2.0.1" as you want.  It cares that the code is always a new one, and always increasing.

Comment: Hey @Erwin1441, do let me know if the provided information solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot share you more details.